# Can't get Bootstrap DateTimePicker to work

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm trying to make bootstrap datetimepicker v3 work according to the instructions [here](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/) , via nuget package but I can't make it to work. My scripts are like this [scripts folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rnetk.png)

I'm making a hospital website for my project and trying to get the patient pick a date in order to get an appointment from a doctor. I'm trying to make the datetimepicker to work but only an empty textbox shows

**Master Page**

```
     <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="CareAndCureFull.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="tr">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - Care and Cure Hospital</title>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>

    <webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/css" />
  <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />


</head>
<body>

    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">Care and Cure Hospital</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a runat="server" id="patientLink" visible="false" 
                        href="~/Patient/PatientPage">Patient Control Panel</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" id="doctorLink" visible="false" 
                        href="~/Doctor/Doctor">Doctor Control Panel</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" id="laborantLink" visible="false" 
                        href="~/Laborant/Laborant">Laborant Control Panel</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" id="adminLink" visible="false" 
                        href="~/Admin/Admin">Admin Control Panel</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Departments/Department">Our Departments</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>


                    <asp:LoginView ID ="LoginView1" runat="server">
                        <AnonymousTemplate>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Register">Patient Register</a></li>
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Login">Login</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </AnonymousTemplate>
                        <LoggedInTemplate>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">Welcome, <%: Context.User.Identity.Name  %> !</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Logout" LogoutPageUrl="~/" />
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </LoggedInTemplate>
                    </asp:LoginView>


                    <%--<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <li><a runat="server" href="~/Register">Patient Register</a></li>
                   <li><a runat="server" href="~/Login">Login</a></li>
                        </ul>--%>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="container body-content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - Care and Cure Hospital</p>
            </footer>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Get Appointment Page**

```
    <%@ Page Title="Get Appointment" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="NewAppointment.aspx.cs" Inherits="CareAndCureFull.Patient.NewAppointment" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2><%: Title %></h2>
   <div class="container">


  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">

      <h3>MENU <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></i></h3>
      <hr>

      <ul class="nav nav-stacked ">
       <li><a href="PatientPage.aspx"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Main Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="ProfileDetails.aspx"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> My Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="NewAppointment.aspx"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i> Get Appointment</a></li>
        <li><a href="PatientPage.aspx"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i> My Appointments</a></li>
          <li><a href="PatientPage.aspx"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-flash"></i> Test Results</a></li>
          <li><a href="PatientPage.aspx"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></i>Show Prescriptions</a></li>




      </ul>

      <hr>

    </div>

      <div class="col-sm-9">


       <h3>Main Page </h3>  

       <hr>

       <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-7">

            <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class='col-sm-6'>
         <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" id="datetimepicker" class="form-control" name="date">
    <label class="input-group-addon btn" for="date">
       <span class="fa fa-calendar open-datetimepicker"></span>
    </label>
</div>
       </div>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           $('.open-datetimepicker').click(function (event) {
               event.preventDefault();
               $('#datetimepicker').focus();
           });
</script>
    </div>

</div>  

       </div>
     </div>
    </div>

  </div>





    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: please help me I must get this to work by tomorrow for school

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made it work by adding

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" />
      <link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

to the NewAppointment.aspx page. This seems to have some issues for web forms with master page, as I made it work in a non-master page webform.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the date picker as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried that, alas that doesn't work too. Only an empty textbox with calender icon beside it shows. It's like it doesn't see the dynamic jquery scripts for some reason

Comment: Can you please share the final HTML generated for that page?

Comment: I've edited my post to include the whole master page and NewAppointment.aspx which uses that master page